# How would a Linux driver call UEFI firmware presented functionality?

Tags: drivers, uefi, source, nvme

For work I'm learning more about computer architecture and I just finished learning about ACPI. From talking to some other engineers my understanding for something like NVMe is that the OEM is going to have a UEFI NVMe driver but then the OS' driver will take over that functionality after boot.

During the boot sequence Linux leverages UEFI's driver and then once it has its own driver loaded swaps to that.

My question is what does that look like in source code? For example, I'm looking at the [NVMe source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/nvme/host/core.c).

I assume there must be some standards based interface exposed by the firmware which the Linux driver must call into? (ACPI?)

Answer (score 0):

In today's world the external devices are usually PCIe. Each PCIe device has its own PCIe configuration space which has a header that looks like this in case of non-bridge devices:

[image: PCIe configuration space]

One of the main tasks of BIOS (or UEFI) is to ask each PCIe device how much memory each of its `Base Address Registers` (=BARs) needs, reserve that regions somewhere in the CPU memory, and write back the start addresses of these regions.

When the OS boots it checks `Vendor ID`/`Device ID` values from the PCIe configuration space for each device and based on that information sets appropriate driver. The driver reads values from the BARs registers that were written by BIOS (UEFI) and works with that memory (or io).

So as you see the main information is written in the device itself and there is no need to ask any UEFI service in the device driver.

As for the Linux API there are several functions to work with those BARs, for example you might want to check out:

```cpp
unsigned long pci_resource_start(struct pci_dev *dev, int bar);
unsigned long pci_resource_end(struct pci_dev *dev, int bar);
unsigned long pci_resource_flags(struct pci_dev *dev, int bar);
```

or

```cpp
int pci_request_region(struct pci_dev *pdev, int bar, const char *res_name)
```

For more complete documentation check out `Linux Device Drivers` book:
https://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch15.html

Or kernel doc on PCI:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/driver-api/pci/pci.html#c.pci_request_region

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/PCI/pci.html